# How to delete a directory in hadoop which has the '[' character in its name

Tags: hadoop, directory, delete-directory

I accidentally uploaded a file to the *"/hadoo[-workshop"* path and I am trying to delete it.

I am using the `hadoop fs -rmr <path>` Hadoop 0.20.2 .
I have tried every permutation of putting the file path in single quotes ('), double quotes ("), and escaping the "[" character with a backslash (), but every time i get an error saying

`rmr: Illegal file pattern: Expecting set closure character or end of range, or } for glob hadoo[-workshop at 15`

Comment: Several years ago, one of my colleagues created an HDFS directory named `*` in the root folder. I remember everyone gathering round his machine watching to see what would happen when he tried to delete it. Fun times.

Comment: @BenWatson what happened in that case?

Comment: I forget sorry, it was back in 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to delete it by using a wildcard (*) in the command.

`hadoop fs -rmr /hadoo*`

I guess "deleting everything that start with the string before faulty character" is good enough.

NOTE: If you use this and you have other directories with a similar name don't use `-skipTrash` to be able to recover the other directories